Draw Line in JMapViewer
Draw Line between two Geo Points in JMapViewer
Same with this question (but since this is was an old question I think i can get a updated answer), how do I create a line (specifically I'm going to create a vault/fault line) using Jmapviewer.
It says that I need to create a class or import a MapPolygonImpl which I don't have map.addMapPolygon(new MapPolygonImpl(route)); in my jar that I downloaded in this site -- https://jar-download.com/download-handling.php.
And reading the answered below that I need the complete source in the github... Which is to be honest I don't know what to do since its a couple folder not a jar. I'm using netbeans as ide. TYIA


Maybe you didn't install the same lib that him (The link that your provide are down),better to check out this one on sourceForge https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmapviewer/ . 
Or if you want to use the source code you just need to take the entire project of what you need and put in on your project and just import in whenever you want/need. You can compil by yourself too.
(but try to avoid linking in actual java source files, this will make it harder for you to keep track of what is your code, and what is someone else's code, especially if you import a lot of projects).
Here a link to the source code of
And here an link of your MapPolygonImpl .

Thank you, I researched a couple src to implement in my project. This tip worked. I'm creating lines as of now.
https://github.com/msteiger/jxmapviewer2
I used this.
